# What happens if you push an item into a stack but the initial capacity has already been met?

Tags: java, stack

```
Stack initial capacity: 5
Object[0] = 'H'
Object[1] = 'a'
Object[2] = 'p' 
Object[3] = 'p' 
Object[4] = 'y'
```

What happens if you try these executions:

```
s.push('i');
s.push('s');
```

Also does a stack implementation using an array have a peek method?

PS. I don't have a computer and i'm merely on my phone asking this. I was just reading a book and this came up as a question...

Comment: try it yourself, and let us know what happen.

Comment: you could try making a program to test this

Comment: sorry I don't have access to a computer and i'm just on my phone and i'm reading a book and this question came up...

Comment: Are you asking about [`java.util.Stack`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) or any other implementation?

Comment: For the implementation of a stack using an array as the underlying data structure.

Comment: We cannot say without more information then you have given us. What Stack implementation are we discussing?

Comment: an array list implementation. should I just post the whole question from the book that i'm trying to figure out?

Comment: An `ArrayList` implementation should grow dynamically. And yes you can peek by getting the element at the top of the List.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The initial capacity is the starting size of the stack's internal array. Once the initial capacity is already met, most implementations will resize the underlying array.

Comment: Note: some implementations may not resize the underlying array at all, but it would be odd to call it an 'initial' capacity if it was not resizeable.

Answer (score 1):

Depends how the stack was implemented. It will cause a stack overflow, and how that is handled is also up to how you implemented your stack.

Ideally, the stack implementation should know when it is at full capacity. When the stack is at capacity and a push is attempted, it will generally throw an exception and not attempt to add an element at all. It is then up to the caller to catch these exceptions and handle them appropriately.

So in short: A good stack implementation will provide error checking and not crash a whole program, a poorly written one will crash. This is using an array as you mentioned, which can have a peek() or top() method.

EDIT: In reply to changing to an ArrayList implementation, then you can't technically overflow since the ArrayList will dynamically grow. But say you set a soft capacity internally, where your stack is not allowed to grow larger than 100 elements. Then YOUR implementation will overflow, not because the ArrayList is full, but because your soft capacity was reached.